# MIPS change calculator

Tags: mips, currency, mars-simulator

So I was assigned a project where basically we have to calculate how many quarters, dimes, nickles, and pennies are in a certain amount of change. Except its not quarters, it's power-of-two dollar bills.
We have:

1024

256

64

16

4

1

dollar bills. The numbers shouldnt matter anyway, but the easiest way to do this would be to use the div function, and just divide by how much money you enter. Say its 2000, just take the quotient and remainder, and continue dividing until I get to 1's. HOWEVER, my instructor wants me to use sll, srl, sra, mul, div, and sub to find these values. How can multiplication or subtraction be used to find these values? Div is definitely the easiest and most efficient,  but im new to this language and could be wrong. I just dont see how they could be used to find these when dividing seems to be the best method. Thanks

Comment: Shift-right and shift-left are equivalent to dividing and multiplying by 2 respectively. The `carry` bit can be useful too. Take it from there.

Comment: I understand that those functions do that, but its still multiplying, and I do not see where multiplying fits into the equation.